# Not sure why syntax error ")" javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to create a function that runs a while loop.

it should run the following:

1. append parameter string1 to div when number in loop is a multiple of 3
2. append parameter string2 to div when number in loop is a multiple of 5
3. else, appends the other string below

I am getting Chrome toolbox error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" for line in script tag starting "for (x % 3 == 0) {". Can't figure out why...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="output"></div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script>

    var this_that = function(string1, string2) {
      var x = 1
      while (x <= 100) {
        for (x % 3 == 0) {
        $(#output).append(x, string1)
      } else if (x % 5 == 0) {
        $(#output).append(x, string2)
      } else {
        $(#output).append(x,'is not a multiple of 3 or 5')
      }
      x++
    }
  }




</script>
```

Comment: It should be `if (x % 3 == 0)` syntax of for is `for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression]){
   statement}` I strongly recommend you to learn basics [For Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` should be an `if` here:

```
for (x % 3 == 0) {
```

should be:

```
if (x % 3 == 0) {
```

Comment: No worries. That happens to us all ...all the time. No problem, glad to help.

Comment: @AustinSefton, if this answer really helped you, then please accept it as an acceptable answer. I think Karl deserves it and an upvote too.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I'm new here

Answer (score 0):

Various errors in your code

1. You need to wrap selector string as `$('#output')`
2. For checking condition you need to use `if`, `for` is using for loop

```js
var this_that = function(string1, string2) {
  var x = 1,
    op = $('#output');
  while (x <= 100) {
    if (x % 3 == 0) {
      op.append(x, ' is a multiple of 3 <br>');
    } else if (x % 5 == 0) {
      op.append(x, ' is a multiple of 5<br>');
    } else {
      op.append(x, ' is not a multiple of 3 or 5<br>');
    }
    x++;
  }
}

this_that();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This `for (x % 3 == 0)` should be like this `if (x % 3 == 0)`.

You just check a condition, *if x is a multiple of 3* and you don't want to iterate some times a block of statements, which is the purpose of a for statement.

As for the error you get, this is caused by the incorrect syntax of the for statement. The correct syntax is the following one:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

For further documentation about the for statement, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Answer (score 0):

use the following

```
var this_that = function(string1, string2) {
var x = 1;
while (x < 100) {
    if (x % 3 === 0) {
        $(#output).append(x, string1)
    } else if (x % 5 == 0) {
        $(#output).append(x, string2)
    } else {
        $(#output).append(x, 'is not a multiple of 3 or 5')
    }
    x++
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `for`?

```
for (x % 3 == 0) //problem lies here. It should be if(x % 3 == 0)
{
        $(#output).append(x, string1)
} 
else if (x % 5 == 0) //if statement never started, then how can we have else if
{
   $(#output).append(x, string2)
} 
else 
{
   $(#output).append(x,'is not a multiple of 3 or 5')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give semicolons before and after condition if you don't want to do initialization and increment 
`for(;x%3==0;)`

Secondly you are using else without if so use `if(x%3==0)`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the other answers you are missing quotes on your selectors

```
var this_that = function(string1, string2) {
      var x = 1
      if (x <= 100) {
        for (x % 3 == 0) {
        $('#output').append(x, string1)
      } else if (x % 5 == 0) {
        $('#output').append(x, string2)
      } else {
        $('#output').append(x,'is not a multiple of 3 or 5')
      }
      x++
    }
  }
```